# KnockoutJS options binding with duplicate values

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm building a simple app with Knockout.js as a proof of concept. As I'm very new to Knockout, the code in this question may be far from perfect and exhibit bad practices, so feel free to let me know if that's the case!

I'm using the [`options`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html) binding to produce the contents of a `select` element:

```
<select data-bind="options: titles, optionsText: 'display', optionsValue: 'value'">
</select>
```

The View Model looks like this:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    this.titles = ko.observableArray([]);
};
```

On DOM ready I am pushing some values into that observable array (each value is an object literal, representing a "title", e.g. "Mr", "Mrs" etc):

```
var data = [
    { value: "Mr", display: "Default Value" },
    { value: "Miss", display: "Miss" },
    { value: "Mr", display: "Mr" },
    { value: "Ms", display: "Ms" }
];
ko.applyBindings(view);
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    view.titles.push(data[i]); //Push titles into observable array
}
```

Don't ask why there are two objects with the value "Mr", that's just the way the data I have to deal with comes. I can't change it. However, this is what causes the problem. I would expect the first object to represent the selected option, but that's not the case. The third object represents the `option` element that actually ends up as the default selection.

I believe this is due to the fact that the observable array causes the `option` elements to be added to the DOM one by one as the loop iterates. Knockout attempts to preserve the selected option by checking it's value. After the first iteration, the selected `option` has the value "Mr". After the third iteration there is another `option` with the value "Mr" so Knockout thinks that it was the previously selected option and selects it.

Here's a [link to a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YuQsz/) demonstrating the problem. The "Default Value" option should be selected, but is not. If you click the button to add another option with the same value again, that becomes selected, but, according to the documentation, it should not.

My question is, how can this behaviour be prevented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you pushing items into array one by one? You could just do:

```
view.titles(data);
```

instead of

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    view.titles.push(data[i]); //Push titles into observable array
}
```

This would also fix your problem - the first item would be selected by default. Also, if you are not planning on adding new items to that array, you could use ko.observable instead of ko.observableArray

UPDATE:
Knockoutjs doesn't seem to like multiple options with the same value. My code won't work properly if you add value binding to a select tag (it will select third item, not first). However, since knockoutjs allows you to access selected object (via value binding), you can remove optionsValue binding and access value via value binding: jsfiddle.net/ej9Ue/1

Comment: Ahh, yes that does fix it initially. But it doesn't help when you add new options. See this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YuQsz/2/ When clicking "Add" the "Default Value" should remain selected but does not.

Comment: This definitely solves the problem with initial data, but the original question highlights a quirk/defect in the way Knockout.js selects previously selected options.  It only checks against the value of the elements, and if more than one option has the same value (which is a valid use case), it could select the wrong one.  A potential solution is to check against value and display text before deciding upon a match.  This is highlighted by adding in new options with the same value, but different display text.

Comment: You are right, knockoutjs doesn't seem to like multiple options with the same value. My code won't work properly if you add value binding to a select tag (it will select third item, not first). However, since knockoutjs allows you to access selected object (via value binding), you can remove optionsValue binding and access value via value binding: http://jsfiddle.net/ej9Ue/1/

Comment: @RomanBataev - I see, very nice. Thank you for your help. I'm having a look at the Knockout source now to see if it would be possible to deal with duplicated option values there rather than having to work around it.