# Iterating over a KnockoutJs observableArray

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

Hi (another Knockout question :-( , sorry)

I have an observable array with five fields (used for data binding etc.) bound to a dropdown.

When a item is chosen from the dropdown, I need a way to iterate through the array and return the additional values that are not present in the dropdown.

Once again, thanks for your help.

Comment: So what have you done so far? What have you tried and not worked?

Comment: Hi, I've just been chasing my tail on this. Say you have three fields BookId, BookName and ShowAuthorInfo (the last field would be used for databinding a dropdown). If I'm right in thinking, only two fields can be present in a dropdown, I need a way to iterate through the array to get the BookID to post back to my MVC action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the entire selected object via "value" binding. You are not limited to two fields.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9161570/knockoutjs-options-binding-with-duplicate-values/9162768)  is a similar question, and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ej9Ue/1/) is a code sample.